# Delphi XE6 - No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page

Tags: string, delphi, unicode, firebird

I get this exception error whenever I want to write data to a firebird db:

> `No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page`

I tried to change the string in my write-function to UnicodeString, but I still get the same error.

I have 2 computers:

- Delphi XE2, with Intraweb 12 (12.2.25)
- Delphi XE6 with Intraweb 14 (14.0.32)

Everything works fine on the IW12 PC, but I have these strange problems in my application on the IW14 computer.

I'm not doing any special string manipulations, only simple read/write to the DB.

If i understand it correctly, this is a Delphi error and not the intraweb's. How can I make it go away?

here is a simple write example to an IBX ibTable that doesn't work :

```
With ibTable Do begin
  Open;
Try
  Append;
  Post;   //  <<---  error when try to Post
Finally
  Close;
End;//Try
```

Comment: You need to understand the text encoding in your db. Why are you using mbcs rather than utf8?

Comment: sorry david, i don't know what "mbcs" is. i do use UTF8 in the DB.
as far as i know, the string type in Delphi XE6 is now only Unicode, i didn't think there could be a problem, when moving from Delphi XE2 to XE6...

Comment: I'm sure you can find out what MBCS is. And do you have any code? Or indeed any more details. Or do you just have this error message.

Comment: btw, thanks to the people who edited my broken english in my question. i didn't know it's possible... cool  :)

Comment: It seems to me that you need to supply more detail.

Comment: The error message itself is from a low-level Microsoft Visual C (or C++) library

Comment: thank you mark. any idea how can i resolve this problem please?